# How do we show loading via highcharts-react-official package

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to use loading option from highcharts. But I am not able to find a way to do it using highcharts-react-official package.

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the place where you need to use it. Both of `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` methods are available on `Chart` object prototype, so for example, if you would like to use it somewhere in chart configuration (e.g `load` event)just call it with on `this`.

If you need to call that methods outside of the chart (e.g somewhere in your component), just need to do the same but using the components `chart` reference.

Here are the examples:

https://codesandbox.io/s/72xq1jo95q (inside of a chart config)

https://codesandbox.io/s/2xl8r2w46r (inside of component)